# Handling java errors in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, blazeds

I am new bie to flex. We are using flex,java,blazeds to develop our application. So we are successfully connected to blazeds but it is showing one error when we are trying to execute the application.the error is:

```
(mx.rpc::Fault)#0       
  content = (null)        
  errorID = 0         
  faultCode = "Server.Processing"             
  faultDetail = (null)          
  faultString = "java.lang.NullPointerException : null"               
  message = "faultCode:Server.Processing       
faultString:'java.lang.NullPointerException : null'            
 faultDetail:'null'"      
  name = "Error"              
  rootCause = (Object)#1       
    cause = (null)         
    localizedMessage = (null)          
    message = (null)
```

If anyone has idea about this issue.Please help me.I am trying to solve the issue.But i didnt get the perfect solution.

Thanks in Advance,
Rakhi

Comment: There is no way that we can find out what is wrong without looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `Error` you got in Flex says that there was an uncaught `NullPointerException` in your java code.

You should examine the processing code of the actual request (debug / encapsulate it in `try-catch`), to see where the NPE is thrown, and handle it, otherwise, instead of the response object, this exception is returned to the flex application.

You can also surround with `try-catch` the request/response processing code in your flex application -in case you don't want to deal with it on server side-, and show a popup/alert message about it. 
But it would be nicer if you'd wrap that `NullPointerException` on server side to a custom `Exception`, so you could handle it more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article about handling the Java errors in Flex, you can find it [here](http://cornelcreanga.com/2010/05/java-exceptions-and-flex/). It aims to cover all the cases (webservices, amf, spring integration).